# Break binary data into lines in a bash one-liner?

Tags: bash

Is there any bash one-liner that would allow me to break binary data coming from a pipe into lines?

As an example:

```
$ echo -ne '\x31\x00\x32\r\n\x33\x34\x35\x00\r\n' | xxd
```

This results in:

```
00000000: 3100 320d 0a33 3435 000d 0a              1.2..345...
```

And I would like to have:

```
00000000: 3100 320d 0a                             1.2..
00000005: 3334 3500 0d0a                           345...
```

In case the binary data contains a new line, I don't mind the message will be split in two or more lines (this will rarely happen in my case).

I have many devices in the field and having to send scripts or programs to do this would be cumbersome. The messages have variable size so `xxd -c` would just work for some messages.

I tried piping the messages to `read`, which correctly breaks the message into lines. But for some reason (probably bash itself) zeros are removed from my messages:

```
echo -ne '\x31\x00\x32\r\n\x33\x34\x35\x00\r\n' | while read; do echo "$REPLY" | xxd; done

00000000: 3132 0d0a                                12..
00000000: 3334 350d 0a                             345..
```

(EDIT: byte offsets can be all zero, that's not a problem. The issue in this last example are the missing zeros in the data part.)

Maybe there is a way to keep the zeros while using `read`? Or maybe my use case is too hairy?

Comment: Do you need the byte offset on the left, as in your first example? In the `read` example xxd only works on individual lines so you lose the offsets on the left.

Comment: The offset is not a problem really. It can be all zeroed.

Comment: Am I right in understanding that you want the character after a newline to appear at the start of a line of 'hex dump' data, with the correct offset at the start of each such line, and that you don't mind if a long line of input is split over multiple lines of output?  I don't think there's a standard utility that does that, but it isn't very hard to write one that does what you want.

Comment: I'm of the "if it doesn't exist then create it yourself" mentality. While I'm not sure if bash can do what you're asking natively (at least without some funky syntax), I'm positive you could create a simple solution in the language of your choice and call your solution from bash. Python comes to mind for me (preference). Do you mind a Python solution that can be called from your shell?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler that's correct, except I don't mind if the offset is all zeros. Will try to make it more clear on the question.

Comment: @h0r53 I hoped there could be a simple trick since I'm sort of bash noob. But I think you're right...

Comment: You can get pretty close with: `printf '\x31\x00\x32\r\n\x33\x34\x35\x00\r\n' | perl -ne 'printf "%08d: ", $c;  print unpack("H* ", "$_") . "\n"; $c += length'`

Comment: @JardelLucca arguably the best thing about bash or any command shell is that it is meant to interact with other programs, including programs you have written yourself. Simply piping data to a custom program intended to do what you what will still look very elegant in bash. Creating a much larger command (that still technically invokes other programs) should certainly work, but it will be less elegant. When I say elegant here I'm referring to ease of use and readability.

Comment: @JardelLucca actually, your second solution `echo -ne '\x31\x00\x32\r\n\x33\x34\x35\x00\r\n' | while read; do echo "$REPLY" | xxd; done` works for me. I'm using zsh. Perhaps consider a new shell :)

Comment: @William Pursell, I've just tested your suggestion and it is definitely good enough! Could you please post your comment as an answer? Thanks!

Comment: @h0r53, thanks for testing it! Would never have thought it would work in another shell...

Comment: `echo -ne` is [generally unreliable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo) -- `echo -e` isn't mandated by POSIX and can be turned off (made to just write `-e` on output) with runtime flags even when the shell is certain to be bash. `echo -n` is likewise only very ambiguously standard-mandated. Much, _much_ better to use `printf %b ...` instead of `echo -ne ...`, as the `printf` approach is guaranteed to work on any POSIX-compliant shell, whereas the `echo` one is very environment-specific.

Comment: I knew about `echo`'s bad fame, but didn't know I could use `%b` in `printf`. No excuses for `echo` anymore! Thanks for the reference also, I will read now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get 90% of what you want with:

```
$ printf '\x31\x00\x32\r\n\x33\x34\x35\x00\r\n' | 
    perl -nE 'printf "%08d: ", $c;  say unpack("H*", "$_") ; $c += length'
00000000: 3100320d0a
00000005: 333435000d0a
```

Comment: Here's another reason to stop procrastinating and start learning perl at once : )